# After update Ignite version to 2.8.0 or 2.9.0, the sql query speed significantly reduced and high cpu used

Tags: java, ignite

I have used ignite for a year, still in version 2.7.5. 
After the ignite version 2.8.0 and 2.9.0 released, I tried to upgrade my ignite version. But I found the sql query speed significantly reduced and high cpu used. It used ten times more than before .   
I have 3 Data node, every node has 4 cpu cores and 8G memory. 1 Logic node, also 4 cpu cores and 8G memory.

The performance in ignite version 2.9.0, zookeeper version 3.5.8:
[query in 2.9.0 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omE3h.png)
[query in 2.9.0 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Mm3.png)
[ignite cpu in 2.9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYvx5.png)
[ignite gc in 2.9.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmuLI.png)

The performance in ignite version 2.7.5, zookeeper version 3.4.13:   
[query in 2.7.5 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXiXj.png)
[query in 2.7.5 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inCI4.png)
[ignite cpu in 2.7.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZbrT.png)
[ignite gc in 2.7.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsYvd.png)

The query code:

```
public LeagueService getLeagueInfo4Init(long humanId, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LeagueUtils.getWorkerPool(vertx).executeBlocking(f -> {
        // query league member info
        List<LeagueMemberEntity> result = leagueMemberEntityDao.selectByHumanId(humanId);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            f.complete();
            return;
        }
        LeagueMemberEntity leagueMemberEntity = result.get(0);
        // query league info
        LeagueInfoEntity leagueInfoEntity = leagueInfoEntityDao.selectByLeagueId(leagueMemberEntity.getLeagueId());
        if (leagueInfoEntity == null) {// no league
            leagueMemberEntityDao.remove(leagueMemberEntity);// no league, delete member info
            f.complete();
            return;
        }
        LeagueInitInfo leagueInitInfo = getLeagueInitInfoBlock(leagueInfoEntity);
        f.complete(leagueInitInfo.toJson());

    }, false, ar->{
        if(ar.failed()) {
            handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar.cause()));
            Loggers.leagueLogger.error("League operate log ====> query league info for init failed; humanId:{}, useTime:{}ms",
                    humanId, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime), ar.cause());
            return;
        }
        Loggers.leagueLogger.info("League operate log ====> query league info for init; humanId:{}, useTime:{}ms",
                humanId, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        if(ar.result() == null) {
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
        } else {
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture((JsonObject)ar.result()));
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

Cause I don't change any code or config, just update ignite version and zookeeper version, I want to know why this happened and how to avoid this?
I'm glad to share more details about the problem if necessary.

Comment: Could you take a heap dump during the operation on both of the versions? Or heap histogram at least.

Comment: @Jerry, it's quite difficult to understand what's happening here. Is it possible to yield a reproducer and share the source code somewhere?

Comment: @VladimirPligin Thanks, I will take a heap dump during the test.

Comment: You can also extract the offender SQL query and run EXPLAIN on it, pasting all columns of the result to the question. Maybe it's something with SQL indexes or planning.